# Accessing numerator and denominator of existing fractions in python

Tags: python-3.x, fractions

I've created fractions using the following code as by using the `fraction` module directly would yield a simplified fraction which I don't want:

```
from fractions import Fraction


class MyFraction:
    def __init__(self, numerator=1, denominator=1):
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator

    def get_fraction(self):
        return Fraction(numerator=self.numerator, denominator=self.denominator)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}/{}'.format(self.numerator, self.denominator)

list_S = []

upper_limit = int(input("Enter upper limit : "))


for a in range(1, upper_limit + 1):

    for b in range(1, upper_limit + 1):

        f_ = MyFraction(a, b)

        list_S.append(f_)

for fraction in list_S:
    # do something to access numerator and denominator of each fraction in list_S
```

Now, list_S contains a few fractions(some are simplified, some are not). How do I access the numerator and denominator of the fractions that are not simplified?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a `get_numerator` and a `get_denominator` method since you do not want to use `get_fraction` as it would simplify your fraction.

Then use the code below to access the not simplified fractions (does not work if you can have 0 as denominator, but it should not be the case):

```
class MyFraction:
    def get_numerator(self):
        return self.numerator
    def get_denominator(self):
        return self.denominator

from fractions import gcd
for f in list_S:
    if gcd(f.get_numerator(), f.get_denominator()) != 1:
        # do some stuff with non simplified fraction
```

Comment: But how do I define the `get_numerator` and `get_denominator` methods?

Comment: Edited answer with methods definition.

Comment: Of course they are objects of the class `MyFraction`.

Comment: To make things simpler, say I have a fraction a/b. a/b is not an object of the class My fraction. How do I get the numerator i.e `a` and the denominator `b` from this fraction a/b ?

Comment: I ran your code and added `print(type(fraction))` in the last loop, here is the output : `Enter upper limit : 2
<class '__main__.MyFraction'>
<class '__main__.MyFraction'>
<class '__main__.MyFraction'>
<class '__main__.MyFraction'>
`

Comment: Is your code indented as in your question? I was assuming it was not but if its the case, indent your methods correctly before running.

Comment: My code has been indented properly in the question. Which part exactly did you assume was not indented properly?

Comment: Your three class methods are not indented properly in the question.